# Blazor PWA working on desktop browsers but not on smartphones

Tags: google-chrome, iis, .net-core, blazor

I'm having an issue related to a PWA which was created using **Blazor**.
This app worked fine until yesterday which starting failing in Google Chrome in mobile devices only.
I'm using **Chrome 91.0.4472.88 Android 8.0**
The weird thing is that the app is working fine in **mobile Opera** and also in any browser in desktop computers.

The app is hosted using IIS 10.0

I debugged a bit and I found this error output

[image: stacktrace picture]

This error is only happening in **Google Chrome mobile version**.

I tried updating to target build net 5.0, maybe this has been solved, but it does not fix the error.

I found some related links to this issue, but no luck

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26698

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/42628

Anyone has an idea how to fix this problem? I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be something with Chrome 91, which has all kinds of significant performance optimizations that, for me, tanked Blazor apps (or at least mine). My app will work on Android Firefox, but I get errors like this, and/or memory errors, since the browser updated to 91. I find it hard to believe that we're the only ones, but I haven't seen any wider concern among Blazor devs.